# this.interval is undefined inside a class function

Tags: javascript, babylonjs

in summarize I want to blink an object material in BJS, so I create two functions `blink()` and `stopBlink()`:

```
function blink(obj, delay, box) {
  var changeMaterial = function(obj, newMaterial) {
    {
      obj.material = newMaterial;
    }
  };
  oldMaterial = obj.material;
  interval = (function() {
    var Toggle = true;
    return setInterval(function() {
      if (Toggle) changeMaterial(obj, box);
      else {
        changeMaterial(obj, OriginalStairMaterial);
      }
      Toggle = !Toggle;
    }, delay);
  })();
}

function stopBlink(obj, duration) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    obj.material = oldMaterial;
    clearInterval(interval);
  }, duration);
}
```

So I called my function inside JQuery Ready function :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btn1").click(function() {
        if(Toggle1)
             blink(stairMesh,100,boxMaterial[0]);
        else 
            stopBlink(stairMesh,500);
      Toggle1=!Toggle1;    
    }
);
```

until now everything works good :), I decided to creat a class and implement my functions inside it (because I want to use polymorphism to redefine `blink()` and `stopBlink()` functions).

```
class A {
  blink() {}
  stopBlink() {}
}
class B extends A {
  constructor(oldMaterial) {
    super();
    this.oldMaterial = oldMaterial;
    this.interval = null;
  }

  blink(obj, delay, box, duration) {
    var changeMaterial = function(obj, newMaterial) {
      {
        obj.material = newMaterial;
      }
    };

    //var oldMaterial=obj.material;

    this.interval = (function() {
      var Toggle = true;
      return setInterval(
        function() {
          if (Toggle) changeMaterial(obj, box);
          else {
            changeMaterial(obj, OriginalStairMaterial);
          }

          Toggle = !Toggle;
        },

        delay
      );
    })();

    console.log(this.interval);
  }

  stopBlink(obj, duration) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      obj.material = oldMaterial;
      console.log(this.interval);

      clearInterval(this.interval);
    }, duration);
  }
}
```

and I create a new object inside ready function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var a = new B();
  $("#btn1").click(function() {
      if(Toggle1)
            a.blink(stairMesh,100,boxMaterial[0]);

      else 
        a.stopBlink(stairMesh,500);

    Toggle1=!Toggle1;  
  }
);
```

The problem is, when I click the button the `blink()` function works goos and my object blinks, but when I click again in order to stop blining it continues to blink!

I tried to `console.log(this.interval)` in `blink()`, it gives me a number (11), but when I console it in `stopBlink()` it is undefined!

Answer (score 1):

Your click handlers are not being bound to the context of your class. An easy fix is to bind them inside your constructor. So, you're setting `this.interval` inside of `blink` but it only exists in the context of that function. By binding it to the class, `this` will refer to the context of the class, instead of the function context.

```
constructor(oldMaterial)
{
   super();
   this.oldMaterial=oldMaterial;
   this.interval=null;
   this.blink = this.blink.bind(this);
   this.stopBlink = this.stopBlink.bind(this);
}
```

Comment: thank u for ur reply, now this.interval is accessible from stopBlink() but the problem is that setTimeout() doesn't work correctly it doesn't stop Blink() after 500 ms